# node / postgres - copy from STDIN result is incomplete. No exception is thrown

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I'm using [node-pg-copy](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams) to bulk import data from a mongodb to a `postgresql db`.

I use observables to map the data coming in from mongodb as it comes in and then write it to the stream that copyFrom is using. Something along the lines of:

```
function writeToStream (source, stream) {

  const trigger = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(stream, 'drain')
  hotsource = source.publish()

  const sub = trigger
    .takeUntil(hotSource.last())
    .subscribe(
      data => stream.write(String(data)) && pauser.next(true), // pauser gets the next row to deal with concurrency. Using debugger, I can see that 'data' is ok every time.
      err => stream.emit('error', err),
      () => !stream._isStdio && stream.end()
    )

  sub.add(hotsource.connect())
}

const textSource = Rx.Observable.from(docs)
  .map(doc => toTextFormat(doc)) // using debugger tools, I can see that every document passes through this method, and returns ok.

const copyStream = pgClient.query(copyFrom(
  `COPY "${table}" (${columnNames.join(', ')}) FROM STDIN`
))


const subscription = writeToStream(textSource, copyStream)
```

Using debugger tools, I can see that every document is correctly mapped and written to the stream.

The script runs without a problem, and finishes without throwing any exceptions. Never the less, when I check the postgres db for the results, there are less rows than expected. **anybody knows why can this be happening?**

**Note:** the script imports several mongo collections into postgres tables, but only two of them have this problem. Also, the number of rows is always the same in those two collections.

**Note II:** this code is a simplified version. The original script deals with concurrency and other potential problems, that I think are not related to this problem.

** Edit:** I've configured postgres to save logs to a file. The logs in the file don't show any error either.